# How to create an XML file from a XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

How do you write an XML file from an System.Xml.XmlReader?

I thought this would be a simple question but whenever I search I seem to be ending up with reading the file to a reader or writing node by node.

The XmlReader object conveys xml that was stored in a database and just needs to come out of the database to a file. Is there any easy way to do this?

```
        SqlCommand dataCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, Conn);
        System.Xml.XmlReader dataReader = null;

        dataCmd.CommandTimeout = 60000;

        Conn.Open();
        dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
        dataReader.Read();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to create an `XmlWriter` and call its [`WriteNode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b.aspx).

For example:

```
using (conn)
using (SqlCommand dataCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, Conn)) {
    dataCmd.CommandTimeout = 60000;

    Conn.Open();
    using (XmlReader dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(File.OpenWrite(...)) {
        writer.WriteNode(dataReader, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: i had one using higher up, but this clean up has made the code even better. thank you.

Comment: For the googlers. 

The file does not get closed if you don't use 

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings{CloseOutput = true}; 

XmlWriter.Create(File.OpenWrite(...),settings)

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way would be to pass it into an XmlWriter, using a method such as this:

```
public void WriteOutXml(XmlReader xmlReader, string fileName)
{
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName);
    writer.WriteNode(xmlReader, true);
}
```