# XML using XMLReader

Tags: c++-cli

I am storing some xml in XMLReader as under (read from url). There there any way I can save this to disk?

```
Stream^ xml= getDataStream( gcnew System::String( m_contentUrl.c_str() ) );

XmlReader^ xmlTextReader = nullptr;
xmlTextReader = XmlTextReader::Create( xml );
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to creating an XML File from a XmlReader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988832/how-to-creating-an-xml-file-from-a-xmlreader)

Comment: This post is in C# and not C++. I want a solution in C++

Comment: You're using CLI, right? There shouldn't be an issue with using an `XmlWriter^` just as explained in that post

Comment: It does not work. When I try the following I get

     XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\data.xml");

error C3622: 'System::Xml::XmlWriter': a class declared as 'abstract' cannot be instantiated

Comment: Using XmlWriter^ has the same effect

Comment: That's not what the answer states. You can do like this: `XmlWriter^ writer = XmlWriter::Create(File::OpenWrite("path_to_xml_to_save"));`. And then you have your `XmlWriter`.

Comment: Thanks. File::Create worked for me. OpenWrite was giving access denied.