# How Do i modify the code to read multiple testcase tags in an asset tag

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

```
 public void ConvertToDirectoryTree()
    {
      XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlDoc);

      while (!xReader.EOF)
      {
        if (xReader.Name != "Asset")
        {
          xReader.ReadToFollowing("Asset");
        }

        if (!xReader.EOF)
        {
          XElement asset = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xReader);

            //We check if the asset is a main branch folder
            if (IsMainBranch((string)asset.Attribute("Name") + (string)asset.Attribute("Version")))
            {
              //If the folder exists already then add it inside this folder
              if (Directory.Exists(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name")))
              {
                XElement testCase = asset.Element("TestCase");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
              }
              //Else we need to create the folder and then add it inside this folder
              else
              {
                XElement testCase = asset.Element("TestCase");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
              }
            }
            //If it is not a main branch folder then we need to handle the name differently
            else
            {
              //If the folder exists already then add it inside this folder
              if (Directory.Exists(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version")))
              {
                XElement testCase = asset.Element("TestCase");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
              }
              //Else we need to create the folder and then add it inside this folder
              else
              {
                XElement testCase = asset.Element("TestCase");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + ((string)asset.Attribute("Version")).Replace(".","_"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I have a function that currently reads an XML file of the following format:

```
<Properties>
 <Assets>

 <Asset Name="" Version="">
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" />  
  </Asset>

<Asset Name="" Version="">
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" />  
  </Asset>
</Assets>
</Properties>
```

Currently it will read the first test case of every asset but then jump out and go to the next asset would anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: Add for loop : foreach(XElement testCase in asset.Elements("TestCase"){}

Comment: @PhillipsJP. Please do not change your question once it's been answered. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code should look something like this

```
        public void ConvertToDirectoryTree()
        {
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlDoc);

            while (!xReader.EOF)
            {
                if (xReader.Name != "Asset")
                {
                    xReader.ReadToFollowing("Asset");
                }

                if (!xReader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement asset = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xReader);
                    foreach (XElement testCase in asset.Elements("TestCase"))
                    {

                        //We check if the asset is a main branch folder
                        if (IsMainBranch((string)asset.Attribute("Name") + (string)asset.Attribute("Version")))
                        {
                            //If the folder exists already then add it inside this folder
                            if (Directory.Exists(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name")))
                            {
                               Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }
                            //Else we need to create the folder and then add it inside this folder
                            else
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name"));
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }
                        }
                        //If it is not a main branch folder then we need to handle the name differently
                        else
                        {
                            //If the folder exists already then add it inside this folder
                            if (Directory.Exists(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version")))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }
                            //Else we need to create the folder and then add it inside this folder
                            else
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + ((string)asset.Attribute("Version")).Replace(".", "_"));
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: yea that worked sorta like I have some asset tags that contain a test case but when I'm feeding it to my Directory.CreateDirectory, the folder is never created is there something wrong with my logic in there or what do you think of how I'm going about creating a directory tree. I'm doing this to later collect a list. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about things but I want to make a list from this XML file and compare to another list where I'm going to compare the name which is the test.case version combined with subversion and the parent folder which is asset name+version

Comment: I can't tell from your xml input how you are getting a tree.  A tree normally would have nested tags; or have a root name for each directory.  Your xml has neither from what you posted.  For a nested tags I usually recommend a recursive algorithm like the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976601/recursion-parsing-xml-file-with-attributes-into-treeview-c-sharp

Comment: by a tree I don't actually mean the data structure tree just a directory tree like I created folders to imitate how a folder structure would look on my computer or in a repository. I'm basically doing this to compare it with another "tree" of directories to see if I have any duplicates. So TLDR: remove from a list that I already have of my current directory tree structure that have the same name and parent (path) from my XML File.

Comment: Also I wanted to know if you knew why some asset tags where they only contained for example one test case between the tags the information between that wasn't picked up, as in theres nothing in the parent folders which is the asset tag. If you my subversion data between the "" is empty so its literally subVersion = "", does that mess up the data?

Comment: The foreach will skip any empty asset folders.  I knew what you meant by tree.  A tree can have many children so there needs to be a method of knowing which children go with each parent.  I don't see the parent-child relationships in your xml file.

Comment: so every asset is the parent folder and every child or subfolder is the test case tags within them

Comment: i made a function to remove all the elements of list a that contain list b(which is the list I created from my xml file). I do this by comparing their name and their parent name thats why I created a directory tree so have that relationship intact

Comment: Is the name in the asset the parent and the name in the TextCase the child?

Comment: almost got it the name of the child is the version+subversion of testcase and the name of the parent is the name+version of asset

Comment: Assuming the parent occurs before the child in the xml and you have no loop (parent is a child of a child) then you need to keep a list (dictionary) of name and path.  For eaxmple you could have a/b/c/d where a to d are the directory names.  'c' name is "b + c" but need to include "a" in path. 'd' name is "c + d" but need to include a & b in path.  So as you parse xml you need to keep then name of every node and the nodes full path.  Every time you you add a directory to your tree you must look up full path in list.

Comment: is it possible to know what the next asset name will be before hand, so my next

Comment: Why do you need a look ahead?  Usually there a better way achieving same results.  I prefer keeping track of last object then using last and current states to make decision.  Code is much simpler and you don't end up with spaghetti code.

Comment: ok how would I do that save it in a temporary variable and refer to it later?

Comment: Usually I create a variable called STATE (usually make an enumeration of possible values) and update as I read the XML.  So I create an IF (or switch)  statement based on what is read from XML and the STATE variable.

Comment: another question: if I want to now have a way to write to my existing XML doc for example add a testcase to an alrerady existing asset or even adding an asset then adding test cases to it or even just editing the value of a test case or asset how would you go about this?

Comment: With xml if you read the entire xml into a XDocument, modify any element/attribute will change document so all you have to do is to use the XDocument.WriteXml() method.  When using an XmlReader you have to save changes to a XmlWrite as shown in following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988832/how-to-create-an-xml-file-from-a-xmlreader

Comment: I don't get it. I just want if im given information such as an asset testcase & version and I want to add it in the right place how would i do thaT?

Comment: it is the same philosophy as adding to the middle of a text file using streams.  You first have to read the file until you get to the point where you want to modify.  Then make the modification.  Then write the changes to a new file.  The ReadXml method is exactly the same.

Comment: I changed my original question @jdweng

Comment: I think the new code I posted, the IF needs to be executed the 1st time you loop in the foreach; and the ELSE needs to be executed every other loop.

Comment: how come I see the my old question and your old answer I don't see the edits now

Comment: My edits are there.  I added a foreach loop which may not be obvious.

Comment: hey someone rolled back everything so I made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923343/edit-xml-doc-whenever-there-is-a-input-to-change-it