# Edit XML Doc Whenever there is a input to change it

Tags: c#, xml, readxml

```
public void ModifyXML(string inputAsset, string test, string version)
    {
      File.Create(Constants.XMLDoc).Close();
      XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlDoc);
      while (!xReader.EOF)
      {
        if (xReader.Name != "Asset")
        {
          xReader.ReadToFollowing("Asset");
        }

        //If we have not reached the end of the file
        if (!xReader.EOF)
        {
          XElement asset = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xReader);
          string branchName = (string)asset.Attribute("Name");

          if (branchName == inputAsset)
          {

          }

        }
      }
    }
```

Hello guys so I'm currently trying to edit an XML Doc whenevr my inputs are not null in my main. My XML looks like this:

```
<Properties>
 <Assets>

 <Asset Name="" Version="">
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" />  
  </Asset>

<Asset Name="" Version="">
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" /> 
  <TestCase Name="" Version="" SubVersion="" />  
  </Asset>
</Assets>
</Properties>
```

So the kinds of edits that are possible are like changes of a current test case s ofor example the version value or sub version or name or even adding a new test case to an asset or adding a completely new asset if need be. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code I posted on previous posting.  How large is you xml input?  The answer would be different fro small xml than large xml.  What inputs do you plan to use for the modifications.

```
public void ConvertToDirectoryTree()
        {
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlDoc);

            while (!xReader.EOF)
            {
                if (xReader.Name != "Asset")
                {
                    xReader.ReadToFollowing("Asset");
                }

                if (!xReader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement asset = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xReader);
                    foreach (XElement testCase in asset.Elements("TestCase"))
                    {

                        //We check if the asset is a main branch folder
                        if (IsMainBranch((string)asset.Attribute("Name") + (string)asset.Attribute("Version")))
                        {
                            //If the folder exists already then add it inside this folder
                            if (Directory.Exists(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name")))
                            {
                               Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }
                            //Else we need to create the folder and then add it inside this folder
                            else
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name"));
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }
                        }
                        //If it is not a main branch folder then we need to handle the name differently
                        else
                        {
                            //If the folder exists already then add it inside this folder
                            if (Directory.Exists(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version")))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }
                            //Else we need to create the folder and then add it inside this folder
                            else
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + ((string)asset.Attribute("Version")).Replace(".", "_"));
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(root + (string)asset.Attribute("Name") + "-" + (string)asset.Attribute("Version") + "\\" + (string)testCase.Attribute("Version") + (string)testCase.Attribute("SubVersion"));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok I really don't get why your doing the old converttodirectorytree function, this isn't the same isssue as before. I finished the last issue thanks to your awseome help this is completely dfferent. Sort of. Its an issue before the last one where the same XML file I will use later for the last problem If the user wants to make changes to it then we need to be able to edit it from the command prompt I made my function editxml which will only be in use if there is an input that is not null.  so I do not have to create directories?? I have no idea why are your writting directories lol

Comment: its more that I have to check if the current aseet and versions exist if they do edit it and if they dont add it